# Java Object reference

Tags: java, object, collections, arraylist

This is regarding the usage of ArrayList returned by another class instance variable.

```
Class A {

    //assigned list of string to it.
    private List < String > newAl;
    //returns the list
    public List < String > getList() {
        return newA1;
    }
}

Class Test {

    public void go() {
        List < String > list = a.getList();
        list.add("");
    }

}
```

In the Test class when i retreive list and manipulate the list.Because of the reference ,class A list also got manipulated.If A is part of third party code.How do I correct my code in Test class so that original object wouldnt be affected?

Comment: return a copy of `newAl`?

Comment: You need to clone the list before sending.

Comment: Or after sending, depending on what A actually is.

Comment: Thanks for replying .I can manipulate only Test class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [ArrayList constructor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#ArrayList%28java.util.Collection%29) takes a Collection so you can use that:

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList(a.getList());
```

I think it's better to do it like this, but depending on what you're doing, you may want to construct the new List in the getter. That also helps type hiding.